# How to display extra desciption in shopping cart on Prestashop

Tags: module, smarty, prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.6

I want to display more content in shopping cart on prestashop same image below (1.6+):

[E.g. add short description to shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyBVU.jpg)

Any helps and solutions

Thank you

Comment: What did you try? If you can't develop on your own, think about hiring a developer.

Comment: I have try using hookDisplayShoppingCart but it only display on Shopping Cart Footer. It can not display below description same above. And I can not find any hook that allow to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in /themes/[your-theme-name]/shopping-cart-product-line.tpl

find

```
<td class="cart_description">
```

before

```
</td>
```

insert:

```
{$product.description_short}
```

Comment: Thank you. And do you know idea to do it which do not need update file tpl, by using hook or module or php code?

Comment: Hi,
I think you do not need to create a new module to just do what you have requested on the example picture, the Matteo's response is OK. At the end you need to update the tpl as it is the presentation layer.
If you want to display more custom information than the product hook retrieves or if you want to create/retrieve new kind of data related to the product then consider the creation of a new module (business or data layer).
I highly suggest you to look http://blog.belvg.com it contains sample and tutorial to help you to understand Prestashop module architecture.